# Loop device possible on Android 2.1 Hero?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, custom-roms, linux, htc-hero, loopback

I'm trying to get Ubunto running on my Android after failing with Debian.

I couldn't mount the image. Now the [Ubunto Tutorial](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/) says that the phone must support loop devices. How can I figure that out, or can anybody give my a yes or no? Thanks

EDIT: I already tried CM7, SalsaSense and some other one that looked very similar to CM7 but I forgot the name... CM7 extra stated that it supports loop devices but it fails on my hero. Could it be that there is some hardware issue that even the right ROM can't fix?

Comment: Trying it is how to find out :P if it doesn't you need to flash a kernel with support - which may or may not be available.

Comment: Hmm, I've heard it said CM specifically doesn't support loopback devices.  It definitely isn't a hardware issue though.  If I had a Hero I could probably help more, sorry

Comment: Any news here?
I have the same problem. If I try losetup I can see that there are loop devices in use so I would expect CM7 to support it. But whatever I do I can't make ubuntu to startup.